# Changing my mind about the PATH when setting up Git for Windows

Tags: windows, git, path

I have Git on my Windows 7 computer, and when I set it up, I chose Git Bash only, to be safe. Now, I want to install Aptana Studio 3, and one of the requirements is that I have Git, with the ability to use Git from the command line, which I understand is not the case now. How can I go back and change that setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just edit the system PATH environment variable to include c:\Program Files\Git\cmd or wherever you installed Git to. The git.cmd and gitk.cmd batch scripts setup the right environment and that is all the installer does for you.

Comment: Oh, I see. So the second option, to only use Git from the command line, but not the other tools, adds the \cmd folder to the path? That's what I was looking for. I did guess that the option to use all the executables was the \bin folder, but I don't think I want to override the command line tools that come with Windows. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried reinstalling Git?  Many windows installers support the concept of reinstalling, allowing you to pick your installation options again.

If that doesn't work, I'd suggest uninstall/reinstall.